# SelectedValues not working in MultiSelectList mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class like

```
 public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Category> CategorySelected { get; set; }
        public static List<Category> GetOptions()
        {
            var categories = new List<Category>();
            categories.Add(new Category() {  ID = 1, Name = "Bikes" });
            categories.Add(new Category() {  ID = 2, Name = "Cars" });
            categories.Add(new Category() {  ID = 3, Name = "Trucks" });

            return categories;
        }
    }
```

In the controller I Fill MiltiselectItems and set selectedValues for it

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
       Category cat=new Category();
       cat.CategorySelected.Add(new Category { ID =1, Name = "Bikes" });
       cat.CategorySelected.Add(new Category { ID =3, Name = "Trucks" });

        var list = Category.GetOptions();
        product.Categories = new MultiSelectList(list, "ID", "Name", CategorySelected);
    }
```

In View Code I have

```
@Html.ListBox("Category", Model.Categories)
```

when run my action SelectedValues aren't working. What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The last parameter of the `MultiSelectList` constructor takes an array of selected `Id`'s not a collection of `Category` complex types.

If you change it to this instead it will work as expected:

```
product.Categories = new MultiSelectList(list, "ID", "Name", cat.CategorySelected.Select(c => c.ID).ToArray());
```

It simply projects it into an array of `Id`'s instead.

See below screen shot:

[image: Screen grab]

Ps I also had to add this to the constructor of `Category` to initialize the collection:

```
public Category()
{
   CategorySelected = new List<Category>();
}
```