# MVC 4 EF - Product / Multiple Categories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**EDIT**: I think I need some sort of view model, but I'm unsure how to handle this relationship.

I'm trying to understand MVC 4 and EF Code First and I'm trying to map many to many relationships.

I have two classes;

```
public class Asset
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }        
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}
```

So I'm trying to allow each Asset to have multiple Categories and each Category may have multiple Assets.

On my create method I have;

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new Asset();

        model.Categories = _db.Categories.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

In my view, the only way I can show these categories is to say; (Note the capital M in Model. I can't use the lower case model as used elsewhere in the view)

```
@model MyProject.Models.Asset
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Assets", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
        {
            <p>@item.CategoryName</p>
        }

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
}
```

When the initial create is called, I can see my asset and it has categories. On the return create method however, its null. I can't work out why. I understand I'm not doing anything to edit these categories in the View, I can't get that far. What I don't understand though is why my model leaves with categories, but comes back with none.

My create return (here my assets categories is null)

```
    // POST: Assets/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Asset model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //error, return to view.
            return View();
        }
        try
        {
             //do stuff
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Ultimately when creating an Asset, I want to be able to list all the categories and allow some selection as to which categories this new asset will belong. If someone could help me work that out, you're my hero. But if I could just understand why what's coming back isn't what I sent out, that would be a start.

Comment: Have you got foreign key relationship setup between two tables?

Comment: Yes, sorry I've updated my question to include it. I have a few other fields in the view and I was trying to trim the syntax for the question.

Comment: return View(); you are not passing back the model in your Create Method that is why you don't see the Categories. return View(model);

Comment: In HttpPost I'm not, yet. Because on HttpPost the asset passed in it's categories are already null, so I'd still be returning null. I do return the model to the view on the Get, which I can then see, in the view. I just can't see them when it comes back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my view, the only way I can show these categories is to say; (Note the capital M in Model. I can't use the lower case model as used elsewhere in the view)

I've always hated that Microsoft uses the `model => model.*` convention through its generated views and tutorials and articles online; it only leads to confusion. In your view `Model` is an actual object instance, namely an instance of what you defined as the "model" for the view. The lowercase `model` you see used in things like `Html.EditorFor` is actually a parameter to a lambda expression. It can be called *anything*. For example, `Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)` and even `Html.EditorFor(supercalifragilisticexpialidocious => supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.Foo)` would work just as well. Although the value that gets passed into this parameter is usually the `Model` object instance, `Model` and `model` are totally different concepts.

> When the initial create is called, I can see my asset and it has categories. On the return create method however, its null. I can't work out why. I understand I'm not doing anything to edit these categories in the View, I can't get that far. What I don't understand though is why my model leaves with categories, but comes back with none.

That is why. You're not doing anything to edit these categories in the view. There's no fields for them to be posted along with the form data, and as a result, the class instantiated by the modelbinder in your action does not contain any data for categories. This is key. The class instance that goes into the view is *not* the same class instance that comes back after something like a post. Each is a unique thing. The post action has no knowledge of anything that came before it; it simply has whatever data was posted. Assuming the action takes a parameter of a particular class, the modelbinder will attempt to new up an instance of that class and bind the posted data to appropriate properties on that class. It doesn't care what was sent to the view originally; it doesn't even care what class it's working with.

> Ultimately when creating an Asset, I want to be able to list all the categories and allow some selection as to which categories this new asset will belong. If someone could help me work that out, you're my hero. But if I could just understand why what's coming back isn't what I sent out, that would be a start.

This is the fun part. First, you absolutely must use a view model for this. In case you're not familiar with view models, they're simply classes that are used as a model for a view, hence the name. What you're passing around here, `Asset`, is technically an "entity", which is a class that is used for data transfer, usually to/from a database. While an entity could be used as a model for a view, as you've done here, it's not really suited for that.

There's a clear conflict of interest, as the needs of a class representing some table schema in a database are vastly different from the needs of a class representing data for a UI layer. That's where view models come in. In the most traditional sense, a view model simply represents the data that will need to be displayed and/or edited in one or more views. It may have many properties in common with a particular entity or it may only have a subset of those properties or even completely different properties. It is the job of your application to "map" from your entity to your view model and vice-versa, so that the logic for saving an entity to a persistence store can be completely abstracted from the logic for how the user interacts with that data.

The reason a view model is so important for your purposes here is that form elements in HTML have certain limitations. They can only work with data that can be represented as a string: things like ints, bools, actual strings, etc. They are particularly unsuited for working with complex objects, like your `Category` class. In other words, it would be perfectly achievable to post back a list of integer ids, representing `Category`s, but it is entirely implausible to post back complete `Category` instances that have been chosen by a user.

Since your entity expects a list of categories and your view will only feasibly be capable of posting a list of ints, there's a fundamental disconnect. Using a view model provides a way to bridge the gap. Plus, it allows you to have other properties, like a list of category choices to populate your select list with, that would be totally inappropriate to put on your entity class.

For your scenario, you'd need a view model like:

```
public class AssetViewModel
{
    // any other asset properties you need to edit

    public List<int> SelectedCategoryIds { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryChoices { get; set; }
}
```

This then allows you to create a multiselect list in your view using:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCategoryIds, Model.CategoryChoices)
```

Now, to populate your view model with data from your entity. In a create view, the entity doesn't exist yet, so you don't need to do any mapping. The only thing you need to do is populate your `CategoryChoices` property so the select list in the view has some data. However, based on the above discussion about data needing to be posted back or else it will be null, since the actual contents of the select list will never be posted, you'll need to populate this in each of your create and edit actions, both for GET and POST. As a result, it's best to factor this logic out into a private method on your controller that each action can call:

```
private void PopulateCategoryChoices(AssetViewModel model)
{
    model.CategoryChoices = db.Categories.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = m.Id,
        Text = m.Name
    };
}
```

Then, in your create GET action, you'll just new up your view model and populate your category choices:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new AssetViewModel();

    PopulateCategoryChoices(model);
    return View(model);
}
```

In the post version, you'll now need to map the posted data onto your `Asset` entity:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AssetViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var asset = new Asset
        {
            Title = model.Title,
            Description = model.Description,
            // etc.
            Categories = db.Categories.Where(m => model.SelectedCategoryIds.Contains(m.Id))
        }

        db.Assets.Add(asset);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    PopulateCategoryChoices(model);
    return View(model);
}
```

The edit GET action is similar to the create version, only this time, you have an existing entity that will need to be mapped onto an instance of your view model:

```
var asset = db.Assets.Find(id);
if (asset == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}

var model = new AssetViewModel
{
    Title = asset.Title,
    Description = asset.Description,
    // etc.
    SelectedCategoryIds = asset.Categories.Select(m => m.Id).ToList()
};
```

Likewise, the edit POST action is similar to the create version, but you're going to map from your view model on to an existing asset instead of creating a new asset. Additionally, because you have a many to many relationship, you have to take extra care when saving the categories.

```
// map data
asset.Title = model.Title;
asset.Description = model.Description;
//etc.

// You might be tempted to do the following:
// asset.Categories = db.Categories.Where(m => model.SelectedCategoryIds.Contains(m.Id));

// Instead you must first, remove any categories that the user deselected:
asset.Categories.Where(m => !model.SelectedCategoryIds.Contains(m.Id))
    .ToList().ForEach(m => asset.Categories.Remove(m));

// Then you need to add any newly selected categories
var existingCategories = asset.Categories.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
db.Categories.Where(m => model.SelectedCategoryIds.Except(existingCategories).Contains(m.Id))
    .ToList().ForEach(m => asset.Categories.Add(m));
```

The extra footwork here is necessary to prevent saving the same relationship twice, resulting in an integrity error. By default Entity Framework creates a join table for many to many relationships that consists of a composite primary key composed of the foreign keys to each side of the relationship.

Comment: I wish I could up vote you more for taking the time to explain this. Perfect and just what I was looking for. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: ATM I'm using (but not sure if best way)
                if(model.SelectedCategoryIds == null)
                {
                    asset.Categories = null;
                }
                else
                {
                      asset.Categories.Where(m => !model.SelectedCategoryIds.Contains(m.Id))
    .ToList().ForEach(m => asset.Categories.Remove(m));

                }

Comment: That scenario is covered by the category removal line. `SelectedCategoryIds` will never be null on post. It will simply be an empty list if the user removed all the selections. The category removal code removes any category association that is not present in `SelectedCategoryIds`.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**
    return View();

you are not passing back the model in your Create Method that is why you don't see the Model is NULL.

```
    // POST: Assets/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Asset model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //error, return to view.
            return View(model);
// If you don't pass back the model to you view you will see model is NULL
        }
        try
        {
             //do stuff
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

2. Cateogries Will always be null in your case, as you can't post back a List like you are doing in your case.

Try Displaying them in a loop, Then the MVC model Binder will be able to bind your list to Model:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Categories[i].CategoryId)
}
```

3. If you want to save SelectedCategories you will have to use [MultiSelect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826280/selectedvalues-not-working-in-multiselectlist-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your categories is null is because you are not binding it on the POST. They are not in fields during the POST.

Try this and see if they are filled out:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Categories[i].CategoryId)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Categories[i].CategoryName)
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying with them not being bound. This is starting to make sense. With what you have I have to change it to @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++) but then I get error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type system.collections.generic.Icollection<MyProject.Models.Category> 

I think this relates to in my question how [at]model relates to the instance passed from the controller and [at]Model relates to the class declaration at the top. Thanks for your help so far. I'm really struggling to grok this.