# Problem with MultiSelectList in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

What's wrong with this code? i don't know exactly why i can't select multiple values from this Dropdownlist (given below)?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Movie</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Movies, new MultiSelectList(Model.Movies, "id", "name"), "Select Movie", new { @class = "form-control"})
</div>
```

Source Code From Google Chrome:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Movies" name="Movies"><option value="">Select Movie</option>
   <option value="1">Movie 1</option>
   <option value="2">Movie 2</option>
   <option value="3">Movie 3</option>
   <option value="4">Movie 4</option>
   <option value="5">Movie 5</option>
   <option value="8">Movie 6</option>
   <option value="9">Movie 7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?  (View-source in the browser).

Comment: its generates the html as expected but i can't select multiple values from it using Ctrl key.

Comment: So the HTML has `<select multiple>` does it?

Comment: @Neil  Look the Question one again please..it added the html source code as well..

Comment: The `<select` is missing the `multiple` part, so the HTML is not 'as expected'.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826280/selectedvalues-not-working-in-multiselectlist-mvc#21828725

Comment: @Neil .. I got it....i have to also specify the `multiple` attribute to `true`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SelectedValues not working in MultiSelectList mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826280/selectedvalues-not-working-in-multiselectlist-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ListBoxFor` instead:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Movies, new SelectList(Model.Movies, "id", "name"), "Select Movie", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Or add `multiple` attribute to the `DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Movies, new MultiSelectList(Model.Movies, "id", "name"), "Select Movie", new {multiple = "true", @class = "form-control"})
```